# Continue insert if one row fails in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I have a question about SQL Server - how to continue insert if one row fails?

I have two tables, `emp` and `empref`. I want insert rows into the `empref` table using `emp` table.

While inserting, one of the rows fails with an "unexpected format" error. `emp` and `empref` both have the same columns, but datatypes are different.

Source : emp

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp]
(
    [id] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [sal] [int] NULL
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [sal]) VALUES (N'1', N'abc', 100)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [sal]) VALUES (N'2', N'xyz', 200)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [sal]) VALUES (N'a4', N'un', 300)
```

In the `empref` ref expected int value but one values alphanumeric values.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[empref]
(
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [sal] [int] NULL
)
```

Expected result in `empref` table :

```
id |name | name 
---+-----+------
1  |abc  | 100
2  |xyz  | 200
```

I tried like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO empref 
        SELECT * FROM emp 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() erro
END CATCH
```

This query is not returning the expected result.

Please tell me how to write the query to achieve this task in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TRY_CAST` to check if the conversion will work

```sql
INSERT INTO empref
  (id, name, sal)
SELECT
  TRY_CAST(e.id AS int),
  e.name,
  e.sal
FROM emp e
WHERE TRY_CAST(e.id AS int) IS NOT NULL;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc8032d51feb5e5b9f5f9401bcdefe10)

> Note: Always specify columns to be inserted into.